# Swift optional method in protocol without objc

Tags: swift

I know, that making some methods in a Swift protocol requires to use `@objc protocol`. The problem is, that I can't use the objective c way, because I have a method in the protocol, which returns a Swift struct. So I'm getting the error, that I can't use the @objc protocol, because my method returns a result, which cannot be represented in objective c.

Unfortunately, I absolutely want to use an optional methods, because there are two methods, which are alternative and the user of my class shall choose, which way he want to use.

Comment: What are the two methods? Can they be combined? Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in the current version of Swift. You may want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Maybe combining will be a way, I'll try, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in this situation is return a class (compatible with Objective-C) which wraps the Swift struct. In other words, just make it so that everything Objective-C sees *is* compatible with Objective-C, and inside that you can do anything you like.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make a struct compatible to Obj C?

Comment: I just told you that you don't have to. That's the point. The class _is_ compatible and that's all that matters. Objective-C doesn't care what's in it.

Comment: That's not completely right! Only a class of an NSObject is compatible. I have to add class myClass: NSObject {. But then it works. (unfortunately I need an initializer for the class -> more code)

Comment: What I said is right. I said a class compatible with Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I've a solution for you.

First is a protocol with the required method(s).

```
protocol A {
  func A() -> ()
}
```

And then, you define as many protocols you need to express the various combinations of optional method(s) you need.

```
protocol APrimo {
  func B() -> ()
}

protocol ASecundo {
  func C() -> ()
}
```

And last but not least, you'll define which protocols your class(es) implements.

```
class AClass: A, ASecundo {
  func A() -> () { }
  func C() -> () { }
}
```

Side note: you can of course define the optional protocols as inheriting from the required protocol. I find the style I used here nicer, but that's just me.

Comment: Sure, that's a way, but it's not very beautiful (in my mind) ;) Nevertheless thank you very much for the answer

Comment: I can understand. Well, for me, this looks pretty much like a class with some extensions. A protocol with some extensions, sort of. I like that symmetry. Future will tell, but I also think this is going to be a common pattern in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

### Protocol Extensions

**Swift 3**

Another way to approach this problem without dealing with objective-C compatibility is to use optionals backed by *protocol extensions*.

Define your optional property or method:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var optionalProperty: Int? { get }
    var requiredProperty: Int { get }
}
```

Implement the default behavior of your optional by extending `MyProtocol` with a *computed property*:

```
extension MyProtocol {
    var optionalProperty: Int? { return nil }
}
```

And now you can create '`MyProtocol` inheriting structs' that don't require the `optionalProperty` implementation.